# Windows Taskbar: Force applications to stay in place when open

Tags: windows, taskbar, desktop, pinning

Can I do something to fix|force the applications to stay in place? I understand it has to do with separate processes and such, but there's a point I don't understand.

taskbar overview:

[image]

What applications I mean:

- Cmder (lamda with green background)
- League of Legends (The "L" icon)

The other applications, as you can see, are all opened at their place.

This might be 2 different issues:

- Cmder is opened in same place on my laptop - so whats the difference? Comparing the Shortcut-Settings by hand doesn't result in any shown difference... But I might oversee something
- League of Legens is on all my Windows machines like it is shown, but can I somehow force to stay in place?

Answer (score 0):

I'm way late to the game, but I had this happen to me with Eclipse IDE, and fixed it by:

- Right click the second icon, and "Pin to taskbar"
- Unpin the first icon